# Undefined Method `authorize_from_request' using OAuth and Twitter Gem in Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, oauth, rubygems

Im getting the following error:

undefined method `authorize_from_request'

Based on the documenation here: http://oauth.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/OAuth/Consumer.html 
That method doesnt exist, but I saw this method used here: 
http://teachmetocode.com/screencasts/oauth-with-the-twitter-gem/ and 
so I'm guessing it was deprecated some time ago, but I can't seem to 
find its replacement and was wondering what other way could I go about 
solving this issue?

Thanks in Advance!

Controller Code:

```
    class TwitterController < ApplicationController
      def index

      end

      def login
        oauth_request_token = oauth.get_request_token(:oauth_callback => "http://gnome.local/twitter/finalize")

        session[:request_token] = oauth_request_token.token
        session[:request_secret] = oauth_request_token.secret

        redirect_url = oauth_request_token.authorize_url
        redirect_url = "http://" + redirect_url unless redirect_url.match(/^http:\/\//)

        redirect_to redirect_url
      end

      def finalize
        oauth.authorize_from_request(session[:request_token], session[:request_secret], params[:oauth_verifier])

        @client = Twitter::Client.new(oauth).verify_credentials

        session[:request_token] = nil
        session[:request_secret] = nil
        oauth_access_token = oauth.get_access_token
        @oauth_token = session[:oauth_token] = oauth_access_token.token
        session[:oauth_secret] = oauth_access_token.secret
      end

      def client
        oauth.authorize_from_access(session[:auth_token])
      end

      def oauth
        @oauth ||= OAuth::Consumer.new(APP_CONFIG[:twitter][:consumer_key], APP_CONFIG[:twitter][:consumer_secret], :site => "http://api.twitter.com", :request_endpoint => "http://api.twitter.com", :sign_in => true);
      end

    end
```

(Original Post: http://groups.google.com/group/oauth-ruby/browse_thread/thread/614b27e4f5d80fab)

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem, the solution is to use [according to the (old) Twitter gem](https://github.com/jnunemaker/twitter/blob/c788810bf856e4d4e705a6971087d8fbf77b7150/lib/twitter/oauth.rb#L45):

```
request_token.get_access_token(oauth_verifier: params[:oauth_verifier])
```